# approximating an $ L^1 $ function with a function of compact support.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Can we approximate an $L^1$ function of several variables $ f(x_1, x_2,.., x_N) $ with a continuos function $ g(x_1, x_2,.., x_N) $ of compact support in sense of $ L^1 $ $\quad $ ?

That is for $\epsilon > 0 $

$|\int_A( f-g )d\mu| \le \epsilon $

$A= g^{-1}$(support g)

Comment: The fact that there are several variables is irrelevant, abstract that away by thinking of a measure on $\mathbb{R}^N$ instead. That said, yes, this is a standard result given in any graduate real analysis text. It helps to prove it in steps: approximate by a compactly supported function, and then approximate that approximation by a continuous function.

Comment: You want $\int_A|f-g |d\mu\le \epsilon,$ not $|\int_A( f-g )d\mu| \le \epsilon.$

Comment: @Ian Not sure why "several variables" is irrelevant as it's exactly the same as saying we're in $\mathbb R^N$ for some $N.$

Comment: @zhw. Because the only thing that matters is that you have a Borel measure on a $\sigma$-finite set. This isn't any different in $\mathbb{R}^N$ than it is in $\mathbb{R}$. So it matters in the sense that it specifies the problem but the actual value of $N$ essentially doesn't appear in the proof.

Comment: @Ian can you reference a book for me or link that has such proof?

Comment: A class taught out of the book by Royden and Fitzpatrick is where I really learned this stuff.

Comment: @Ian I found the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found out the answer is quite easier than I thought:

using bump functions [bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function)

let $1\ge n>0$

$r(x)=-{\frac {n}{x^2-a^2}}$

$h(x)=-{\frac {n}{b^2-x^2}}$

$\psi(x)_n =
\begin{cases}
e^{h(x)+r(x)},  & \text{if $a< x< b$ } \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

$\psi(x)_n$ is continuos and has compact support.

any step function $s(x_1,x_2,...,x_N)$ can be approximated with a continuos function of compact support over the box $a^Nb^N$.
Proof:
define $g_n=\psi(x_1)_n\psi(x_2)_n....\psi(x_N)_ns(x_1,x_2,...,x_N)$

$ \lim\limits_{n\mapsto 0} g_n =s(x_1,x_2,...,x_N)$

$|g_n| \le |s(x_1,x_2,...,x_N)|$

it follows from dominated convergence theorem:

$\lim\limits_{n\mapsto 0}\int_A|g_n-s|d\mu=\int_A\lim\limits_{n\mapsto 0}|g_n-s|d\mu=0$

since every function $f$ in $L^1$ is the limit almost everywhere of a sequence of step functions {$s_n$}: for some $\epsilon>0$

$\int_A|f-s_n|d\mu \le \epsilon$ for some inter $n>0$

and we can have sequence {$g_m$} of continuous functions each with compact support such that:

$\int_A|g_m-s_n|d\mu \le \epsilon$  for some $1 \ge m\ge 0$

$\int_A|f-g_m|d\mu =\int_A|f-s_n-g_m+s_n|d\mu \le \int_A|f-s_n|d\mu+|g_m-s_n|d\mu \le 2\epsilon$

Comment: (note that once your know $L^1$ is the closure of compact support step functions for the $\|.\|_1$ norm, it is obvious that the compact support step functions are dense in $L^1$)  so the problem is really starting from the [Lebesgue integrable definition of $L^1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces). an usual approach is to convoluate $f \in L^1$ by $h_n(x) = \frac{h(nx)}n$ where $h\in   C^\infty_c$, then $f \ast h_n$ is $C^\infty$ and $L^1$, and multiplying it by another $C^\infty_c$ function approximating $\chi_{[-n,n]}$ yields a $C^\infty_c$ sequence converging to $f$ in $L^1$

Comment: What you've done here is actually higher-powered machinery than you needed. All you need is $\sigma$-finiteness (so that the simple functions can be taken to have finite measure support) and Borel regularity of the measure (so that you can approximate measurable sets by open sets). Then Lusin's theorem (which doesn't need any "differential" structure) does the job for you. This proof is probably *easier*, because you're using more or less all the machinery that you have available to you in $\mathbb{R}^N$, but a more general proof is not that difficult.

Comment: @Ian : To who is your comment addressed ? Because the problem is that he starts from "step functions are dense in $L^1$" so that obviously $C^\infty_c$ functions are dense in $L^1$. And to me that $\chi_E$ where $E$ is a measurable set can be approximated in $L^1$ by $\chi_{A_n}$ where $A_n$ is a sequence of open sets is useful for proving $\|f-f \ast h_n\|_{L^1} \to 0$ in what I wrote

Comment: My comment is to s.t.a.l.k.e.r_2133